# MongoDB filter in a list (size unknown) of Nested documents

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, subdocument

So I have this :

```
{
  uuid: 29f26148-4d55-4b4b-8e07-900fda686a67
  ...
  ...
  punishments: [
         {
           type: "MUTE"
           issued: *time_issued*
           expire: *expire_time"
           ...
         },

        {
           type: "BAN"
           issued: *time_issued*
           expire: *expire_time"
           ...
         },

         ... (etc the list goes on)
         ...
       ]
}
```

How can I query in "punishments" to get all of the ones that are still not expired (I also need the uuid in the parent document but for this I think projections can do it) ?

Comment: Is punishments is an array or like a hashmap as in your question?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Ok i did some research and yes punishments is an array

Comment: Then can you update your sample document in the question?

Comment: I just edit it now